# Need Help Modifying WooCommerce Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook, elementor

Need Help Modifying WooCommerce Product Page - Using Elementor or Other Plugins?

I'm currently working on a WooCommerce project and have run into a bit of a roadblock. I'm relatively new to WordPress and WooCommerce, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to modify the single product page.

- I need to add the review part, a descriptive text a slider for similar projects, and some adjustments in the header and footer.
- I need to customize the layout and design of the single product page.
- I need to add the review part, a descriptive text and a slider for similar projects, and some adjustments in the header and footer.
- I made a backup for the website using All in one WP Migration
- I'm considering using Elementor, but I'm not sure if it's the right tool for the job , because there is already lot of folders and files with code of the page and the page will be transferred to another website later .

**Specific Questions:**

Can I use Elementor to customize the single product page, and if so, how should I go about it?

Are there any specific plugins you recommend for modifying WooCommerce product pages?

What's the best way to understand the structure of WooCommerce template files? I'm a bit lost in the folders.

Specifically , is it safe to create the single product page and modify it with elementor ??

**Additional Info:**

- I've tried storeCustomizer but the results are limited.
- I've looked into the WooCommerce documentation, but it's a bit overwhelming for me right now.

Any guidance, tips, or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can I use Elementor to customize the single product page?**

Yes, you can use Elementor to customize the single product page. Elementor is a powerful page builder plugin that allows you to create custom layouts without writing any code. It has a wide range of widgets and modules that you can use to add new content to your pages, including reviews, descriptive text, sliders, and more.

**How should I go about customizing the single product page with Elementor?**

To customize the single product page with Elementor, follow these steps:

Create a new single product page template.
Open the new template in the Elementor editor.
Add the widgets and modules that you want to use to your page.
Customize the design of your page using Elementor's drag-and-drop interface.
Save your template.

**Are there any specific plugins you recommend for modifying WooCommerce product pages?**

In addition to Elementor, there are a few other plugins that I recommend for modifying WooCommerce product pages:

[WooCommerce Product Customizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-designer/): This plugin allows you to customize a wide range of aspects of the product page, including the layout, style, and functionality.

[WooCommerce Product Page Builder](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-page-builder/15534462): This plugin is a drag-and-drop page builder specifically designed for WooCommerce product pages.

**What's the best way to understand the structure of WooCommerce template files?**

The best way to understand the structure of WooCommerce template files is to read the WooCommerce documentation. The documentation includes a detailed explanation of the files and functions that are used to create the WooCommerce templates.

**Specifically, is it safe to create the single product page and modify it with Elementor?**

Yes, it is safe to create the single product page and modify it with Elementor. Elementor will not overwrite the existing template files. If you need to revert to the original template, you can simply delete the new template that you created.

I hope this helps!